# Help writing a recurrence relation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have this recurrence relation which is defined as:

$x_{j+1}-2x_j+x_{j-1}=1$

$j=1,2,...$

My task is to write two MATLAB functions, the first one should generate a fixed number $n$ of elements of the sequence $x_j$. The only user input should be $n$.

The second function should compute terms up until $x_j > x_{max}$ and then stop. The value $x_{max}$ should be the input.

In both cases, I need to provide two initial conditions chosen at random in $(0, 1)$ in the code.

Can anyone help me here?

EDIT: I can't seem to add comments - sorry I didn't realise this was the wrong area, can someone delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence is polynomial.
This is your first function:

```
function res=u(n)
res=(0:n).^2/2+interp1(0:1,rand(1,2)-[0 1],0:n,'linear')
```

The second function should solve the second degree polynomial and then use u(ceil(n_root))